# why style-loader affects the actual class names applied?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

I'm new to webpack configuration, and been learning the usage of loaders.
from what I understand :

- css-loader reads the files and resolve imports and url's found there (and can also create css modules if set via options or change the classnames to scoped names...)
- style-loader generate js that, in turn, inject  tags to the DOM.

When I use css-loader with style-loader I get both the scoped class-names, and the style injected - as meant to be.

What's weird for me, is when I remove the style-loader, indeed no styles are injected, But, also the class names on the components changed to undefined.
why is the change related to the style-loader not being used ?

for reference - this is the module part in the webpack.config.js

```
  module: {
rules: [
  {
    enforce: "pre",
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "eslint-loader",
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use : [
        ***remove this*** --->'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
          modules: true
        }
      },
      'postcss-loader',
      'sass-loader'
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    use : [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader'
    ]
  }
]
```

}